# What is a "warp bubble"?

Tags: propulsion, physics

There has been rampant speculation relating to the EMdrive lately.    One such speculation talks about "warp bubbles".   I'm not familiar with this concept.   Is there a scientific definition of what a warp bubble is?

Is there any "vague" physics backing this up?

Is it purely uninformed media making things up to sound smart?

[NASA May Have Just Accidentally Discovered Faster than Light Travel](http://www.sciencetimes.com/articles/5966/20150430/nasa-accidentally-discovered-faster-light-travel.htm)

(I'm not asking how a device would create such a thing, simply what the scientific definition of such a concept is)

Comment: This might be a better fit for [physics.se], but please don't cross-post. If our community votes it as off-topic, we will migrate it to a more suitable site for you. In simplest terms however, a warp bubble is a distortion in a spacetime continuum that, through time-varying electromagnetic fields, bends spacetime to stretch ahead of it and contracts behind it, creating a region around it (the _bubble_) that isn't a subject to relativistic limitations of spacetime. Note that [tag:emdrive] isn't about FTL, but a quantum vacuum drive that allegedly doesn't require reaction mass to produce thrust.

Comment: The EmDrive has nothing to do with the notion of a "warp bubble". References to it in the Science Times article may be due to the fact that the same NASA lab working on EmDrive is also performing experiments to investigate the physics and possible application of the Alcubierre Metric (colloquially described as "warp bubble"). EmDrive is about reactionless drive and the possibility of its application to spaceflight at non-relativistic speeds (interplanetary travel). The Alcubierre Metric is the one which invites more grandiose speculation on the possibility of FTL travel.

Comment: @AnthonyX Other articles, seem to make a relationship between the EMdrive and a "warp bubble" http://www.inquisitr.com/2040259/did-nasa-just-accidentally-produce-a-warp-bubble-emdrive-could-lead-to-warp-drive/ Did NASA Just Accidentally Produce A Warp Bubble? EmDrive Could Lead To Warp Drive.      This inquisitr article mentions something about a beam of light going faster then the speed of light.   Do "warp bubbles" apply at both the micro, and micro level?

Comment: MarsOne Or Bust, it would be nice if you could re-word your question either to eliminate all refs to EmDrive ("what are warp bubbles?") or to focus on finding out what the hype about alleged NASA experiments is about. We cannot make the choice for you right now.

Comment: For reference, here's the (closed) most recent question on EmDrive at Physics SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179394/what-are-the-evidences-that-support-the-emdrive

Comment: NSF blog that started the wave: http://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2015/04/evaluating-nasas-futuristic-em-drive/

Comment: NSF thread about the same: https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=36313.0 ; one has to look for posts by Paul March.